# Custom Chrome extension not working the way it should

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop an extension for Chrome, that is supposed to do the following:

Upon a new webpage being visited by the user, and BEFORE it is displayed to the user, process the following actions:

1. Locate the largest CSS file, referenced by the page to be loaded.
2. Parse its contents, and create a count of the number of occurrences of a specific string, for instance "test_string"
3. Compare that count against a local database text file, called "db.txt".

3a. If the two counts match, immediately redirect the user to another web page.

So far, I've got the following code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Page Blocker",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "icons": {
    "48": "icon.png"
  }
}
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
  function (details) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { action: "webRequestCompleted", details: details });
    });
  },
  { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }
);

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  // Initialize the local storage
  chrome.storage.local.set({ thresholdCount: 0 }, function () {
    console.log("Initialized local storage");
  });
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "redirectPage") {
    console.log("Redirecting page");
    chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, { url: "http://1.1.1.1/error.html" });
  }
});
```

content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (request.action === "webRequestCompleted") {
    const details = request.details;
    if (details.type === "stylesheet") {
      // Get the size of the CSS file
      const cssSize = details.encodedDataLength || details.transferSize;

      // Retrieve the largest size from local storage
      chrome.storage.local.get(["largestCssSize"], function (result) {
        const largestCssSize = result.largestCssSize || 0;

        // Compare the size with the largest size
        if (cssSize > largestCssSize) {
          // Fetch the threshold count from an external file
          fetch(chrome.extension.getURL("db.txt"))
            .then(response => response.text())
            .then(thresholdCountString => {
              // Parse the threshold count from the file
              const thresholdCount = parseInt(thresholdCountString.trim(), 10);

              // Count occurrences of "maimuna" in the CSS file
              fetch(details.url)
                .then(response => response.text())
                .then(cssText => {
                  const count = (cssText.match(/maimuna/g) || []).length;

                  // Compare the count with the threshold count
                  if (count === thresholdCount) {
                    // Block the page and show a message
                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "redirectPage" });
                  }
                  
                });
            });
          
          // Update the largest size in local storage
          chrome.storage.local.set({ largestCssSize: cssSize }, function () {
            console.log("Updated largest CSS size in local storage");
          });
        }
      });
    }

  }
});
```

The extension is loaded fine, but does nothing upon visiting a test page, that is specifically designed to get redirected to the preset page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It can't be implemented in Chrome. The page loads independently of your code and there's no way to pause this process. In Firefox you can do it by returning a Promise from the webRequest listener that you would resolve after fetching the data.

Comment: What if I substituted blocking the page from loading with an immediate redirect to an error page, hosted somewhere on the Web?

Comment: Sounds like terrible UX. It doesn't have to be a web page: you can redirect to a local page inside the extension, exposed in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/web_accessible_resources/). A proper solution would be to make a proxy server.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect a redirection to a new page, instead of blocking the currently loaded one, but it doesn't seem to make a difference. Nothing visible happens when I run the test page through the browser.

Comment: When the request completes the page hasn't yet loaded and there are no content scripts. Only html was received. Rework the entire thing: do everything in the background script without using content scripts. Use details.tabId instead of active tab in webRequest listener. Also consider using onHeadersSent event as it happens earlier. Specify `types: ['main_frame']` to exclude requests for fonts/css/images/js. Use devtools for the [background script](/a/10258029) to debug the code.